# Trigger when something is clicked in javascript only?

Tags: javascript, events

My app shows an error message. I want to remove the error message when user click something in my page.

I need only javascript.
I tried this code,

```
$(body).click(function(){});
```

but it is using jquery.

Comment: `document.onclick = function(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('error-controller').style['display'] = 'none';
}
```

```css
#error-controller {
  display:block;
  background:#e8e8e8;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px
}
```

```html
<div id="error-controller">Heads up! Error</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="submit()">print</button> <!--triggers a function-->
<p id="hello"></p>
<script>
function submit() {
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```